# Best way to pass user information around iOS app?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that needs to keep user-specific information and to access this information from any point in the application. My original solution this was to pass a User object around to every view controller that the app walks through, but I find this solution to be inelegant and bulky. I was wondering if there was a better way to keep universal information for the entire app to use, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to keep this data around if they leave your app or just for that instance of the app running? If it is just for that instance of the app running you could create a singleton instance of a Person Object, obviously you will need to write a the Person class yourself. If you want to have it come back later in another instance of the class I suppose you could use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Yes,only for that instance. I  will look into making a singleton class, thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately I am about to leave work and don't have time to write one right now but as soon as I am at a computer again I will give an answer.

Comment: you should try with notifications, if you want to have access to some objects in every class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a singleton class. That can be called from any other class.

MyUser.H

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyUser : NSObject {
    NSString *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;

+ (id)sharedUser;

@end
```

MyUser.m

```
#import "MyUser.h"

@implementation MyUser

@synthesize someProperty;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedUser {
    static MyUser *sharedMyUser = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyUser = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyUser;
}

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      someProperty = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Default Property Value"];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
}

@end
```

Then you can reference the singleton from anywhere by calling the following function:

```
MyUser *sharedUser = [MyUser sharedUser];
```

Of course, you can use **NSUserDefaults** to populate the singleton when it is loaded and even use it to save the state.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

For small amounts of data, I recommend using NSUserDefaults. It can be used like a dictionary, where you can set values for keys, and retrieve these values later on anywhere in the app.

For larger amounts of data, Core Data may be the best solution. You could have an entity named User, which stores all the data for the user.

If you are a subscriber to RayWenderlich.com, there are 7 great video tutorials on data storage. They talk about NSData, the File Manager, Plists, encoding and decoding objects, NSUserDefaults, XML, and JSON, which should cover most of your needs. They also have a Core Data by Tutorials book coming this fall, and already have tutorials on Core Data on the site.

Comment: i'm not really sure if this is what he is asking about.

Comment: @BogdanSomlea He just wanted user specific information, which is a good place in NSUserDefaults. His wording is pretty vague, so any of these solutions *could* be what he is looking for.

Comment: but he does not want to have the information only in the same session of the app, maybe in other session he needs just part of the information, but he will still have the information there

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property to your application delegate to store your `User` object. You can then access it by using `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Answer (score 0):

just send notifications like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:yourInformation];
```

and in every class that you need the information get it with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(workWithInformation:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];
```

make everything with your information in this method

```
- (void)workWithInformation:(NSNotification *)notification {
 id info = [notification yourInformation];
}
```